# axios onUploadProgress returns immediately 100% progress on android using react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

> React Native android returns first 0% then immediately 100% progress for file upload but in the case of iOS it perfectly shows the progress with the loaded and total content.

```
await axios({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            // timeout: 60  30  1000,
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.token,
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },

        onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
            let percentage = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
            console.log("PERCENTAGE ", percentage)
            self.setState({ progress: percentage, isFileUploading: true })

        },
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this has been reported as an issue in axios:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3720

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3469